# Foreign key constraint violation JPA

Tags: java, jpa, jakarta-ee

I have my auction house project and 3 entities here:

```
public class Auction implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private long id;
@ManyToOne
private UserAccount user; //nie daje sie id tylko obiekt
private String description;
private String title;
private double price;
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "auction", orphanRemoval = true, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private List<Offer> offers = new LinkedList<Offer>();
 private Timestamp creationTimestamp = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
 private Timestamp expirationTimestamp;


public void addOffer(Offer o) {
    offers.add(o);
    o.setAuction(this);
}




public class Offer implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private double price;
    @ManyToOne
    private Auction auction;
    @ManyToOne
    private UserAccount user;
    private Timestamp creationTimestamp = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());

public class UserAccount implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String username;
    private String email;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", orphanRemoval = true, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Offer> offers = new LinkedList<Offer>();
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user",fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Auction> auctions = new LinkedList<Auction>();

public void addAuction(Auction a) {
    auctions.add(a);
    a.setUser(this);
}

public void addOffer(Offer o, Auction a) {
    offers.add(o);
    o.setUser(this);
    o.setAuction(a);
}
```

Adding data to database works smoothly but removing linked rows works only for UserAccount. Firstly I create user and then I add auctions with offers. 
When I try to remove user's auction error appears:

```
Internal Exception: org.apache.derby.shared.common.error.DerbySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: DELETE on table 'AUCTION' caused a violation of foreign key constraint 'OFFER_AUCTION_ID' for key (1).  The statement has been rolled back.
Error Code: 20000
Call: DELETE FROM AUCTION WHERE (ID = ?)
    bind => [1 parameter bound]
```

Can you tell me what is the solution, am I right thinking it's relations fault, auctions and users should not share offers in this case?
Testing code:

```
    UserAccount user = new UserAccount();
    user.setUsername("filip");
    user.setEmail("example100@gmail.com");

    Offer offer = new Offer();
    offer.setPrice(2200d);
    Offer offer2 = new Offer();
    offer.setPrice(2500d);

    Auction auction = new Auction();
    auction.setDescription("opel na sprzedaz");
    auction.setPrice(2000d);
    auction.setTitle("opelek na sprzedaz");
    auction.addOffer(offer);
    auction.setExpirationTimestamp(new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis() - 86400000l));

    user.addOffer(offer, auction);
    user.addOffer(offer2, auction);

    user.addAuction(auction);

    userEjb.save(user);
```

Comment: You probably forgot to add the offers that you create to the list of offers of its owning auction. Without code, all we can do is bets.

Comment: Testing code added, sorry

Comment: Just what I thought: your UserAccount.addOffer() method sets the auction of the offer, but doesn't add the offer to the auction's offers.

Comment: Try to set  o.setAuction(this); before you add it to you list offers.add(o) and tell if it works ? and do same for addAuction in the UserAccount  class

Comment: I am very grateful to you, it works perfectly now.

Answer (score 0):

It seems it's using EJB spring + hibernate solution in your project.
Maybe there are 2 tables user and offer in database.
and they are related by foreign key.
The reason of current error is not relations fault.
You need to check that the "On Delete" field of foreign key is set to "CASCADE" in user and offer tables.

Comment: Spring + EJB (JavaEE) ! I think that's not good implementation .